# How do you get the hardware back button on VideoCastControllerActivity to work?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

Once my app starts playing and VideoCastControllerActivity shows up, the hardware back button won't take it back to my activity. The actionbar back button works just fine. I don't see any errors on the logs or anything and looking at the VideoCastControllerActivity I didn't see anything obvious trying to capture the back button behaviour or anything. To start it I am calling `startCastControllerActivity`.

Here is the chunk of my manifest declaring it:

```
<activity
                android:name="com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.player.VideoCastControllerActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:parentActivityName="com.mypackage.myactivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.mypackage.myactivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The CastCompanionLibrary doesn't try to capture the back button at all, so it should work just fine. Please try the CastVideos-andrid (which uses that library) to confirm that.

Comment: Found the bug,  `super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);` isn't being called because of the `mVolumeIncrement` check.

Comment: I updated CCL to make sure if user hasn't set a value for VOLUME_INCREMENT, the default logic in that activity handles that correctly; documentation is also updated.